# How to remove invalid edges in graded directed acyclig graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

The following graph sample is a portion of a directed acyclic graph which is to be [layered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) and cleaned up so that *only edges connecting consecutive layers are kept*.

So what I need is to eliminate edges that form "shortcuts", that is, that jump between non-consecutive layers.

The following considerations apply:

1. The bluish ring layering is valid because, starting at 83140 and ending at 29518, both branches have the same amount (3) of intermediary nodes, and there is no path that is longer between start and end node;
2. The green ring, starting at 94347 and ending at 107263, has an invalid edge (already red-crossed), because the left branch encompasses only one intermediary node, while the right branch encompasses three intermediary nodes; Besides, since the first edge of that branch is already valid - we know it pertains to the valid blue ring - it is possible to know which is the right edge to cross-out - otherwise it would be impossible to know which layer should be assigned to node 94030 and so it should be eliminated;
3. If we consider the pink ring *after considering the green one*, we know that the lower red-crossed edge is to be removed.
4. BUT if we consider *only* the yellow ring, both branches seem to be right (they contain the same number of inner nodes), but actually they only seem right because they contain symmetric errors (shortcuts jumping the same amount of nodes on both branches). If we take this ring locally, at least one of the branches would end up in wrong layers, so it is necessary to use more global data to avoid this error.

[image]

My questions are:

1. What typical concepts and operations are involved in the formulation and possible solution of this problem?
2. Is there an algorithm for that?

Comment: What you're trying to do is close to a transitive reduction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction ... but not quite.  Are you sure you don't really want a transitive reduction?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yeah I'm pretty sure. Specifically, the crossed-out edges (with a red X mark in the image) should not be in the graph, but would be kept if using a Transitive Reduction. They should not be in the graph because it would imply a connection between nodes that are not actually connected (this graph is generated via image-processing and these shortcuts result from artifacts in the original image)

Answer (score 1):

First, [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the graph.

Now from the beginning of sorted array, start [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and try to find the proper "depth" (i.e distance from root) of every node. Since a node can have multiple parents, for a node `x`, `depth[x]` is maximum of depth of all it's parents, plus one. We initialize `depth` for all nodes as `-1`.

Now in bfs traversal, when we encounter a node `p`, we try to update the depth of all it's childs `c`, where `depth[c] = max(depth[c],depth[p]+1)`. Now there are two ways we can detect a child with shortcut.

- if `depth[p]+1 < depth[c]`, it means `c` has a parent with higher depth than `p`. So `edge p to c` must be a shortcut.
- if `depth[p]+1 > depth[c]` and `depth[c]!=-1`, it means `c` have a parent with lower depth than `p`. So `p` is a *better* parent, and that other parent of `c` must have a shortcut with `p`.

In both cases, we mark `c` as problematic.

Now our goal is for every 'problematic' node `x`, we check all it's parent, whose depth should be `depth[x]-1`. If any of them have depth that is lower than that, that one have a shortcut edge with `x` that needs to be removed.

Since the graph can have multiple roots, we should have a variable to mark `visited` nodes, and repeat the above thing for any that's left unvisited.

This will sort the yellow ring problem, because before we visit any node, all it's predecessors has already been visited and properly ranked. This is ensured by the topological sort.

(Note : we can do this by just one pass. Instead of marking problematic nodes, we can maintain a `parent` variable for all nodes, and delete edge with the old parent whenever case 2 occurs. case 1 should be obvious)

Comment: simply put, if in a directed acyclic graph a node has `c` childs, it's position in topologically sorted array MUST be before any of it's child....

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, I'm gonna take a good read at it. To be honest I found the third and fourth paragraphs (the ones that explain criteria to mark points [first pass] and then to remove them [second pass]) a bit confusing. Perhaps complementing the math code notation with "plain english" algorithm description would be nice, if you feel like it ;o)

Comment: Also, note that incidentally the graph _drawing_ is topologically sorted (I used GraphViz which usually does that), but my data-structure is not, and so I'm gonna find out how to achieve that.

Comment: @heltonbiker, admittedly, it was a bit confusing. how about now?

Comment: After the whole day studying, I would say that what I actually need is a __graph layering algorithm__. If I am able to assign a layer number to every node, I can easily identify the invalid nodes, ending up with a "clean", layered graph structure. I'v even rephrased my question to reflect these better insights.